# NameError: name 'urlpatterns' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to show an image using "ImageField"

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    )
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url


urlpatterns=[
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

write this total code in your urls.py

Comment: what error are you getting? edited my ans, give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You need initialise `urlpatterns` first. Like,

```
urlpatterns = []
```

Then, you can do this,

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

set your `settings.py` like this,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    )
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Comment: that give me this :

Comment: 'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Empty static prefix not permitted'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```